# How to change to private network in ethereum wallet?

Tags: testnets, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

How can I change to the private network in the ethereum wallet. I just got two mainnet and testnet in the wallet. Appreciate your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run 'geth.exe' with your private networkid, for example:

```
geth --networkid="38712" --datadir "D:\GethDataDir38712" --genesis "genesisblock.json" console 2>>geth38712.log
```

and then run the ethereum wallet. It will connect automatically to your private net.

Answer (score 0):

From [Github - Mist - getIpcPath.js, lines 10 to 23](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/master/modules/ipc/getIpcPath.js#L10-L23), the IPC path is hardcoded to be:

```
module.exports = function() {
    var p = require('path');
    var path = global.path.HOME;

    if(process.platform === 'darwin')
        path += '/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc';

    if(process.platform === 'freebsd' ||
        process.platform === 'linux' ||
        process.platform === 'sunos')
        path += '/.ethereum/geth.ipc';

    if(process.platform === 'win32')
        path = '\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc';
```

You can change the data directory that `geth` uses, but you will have to use the `--ipcpath` option to set the IPC path back to the default IPC path.

So for Linux, you have to separately run the `geth` command:

```
geth --dev --datadir /tmp/devdata --ipcpath $HOME/.ethereum/geth.ipc console
```

Then start Ethereum Wallet as normal. There should be **PRIVATE-NET** indicator on the top of the window.

Note that there is a `geth` executable packaged with the 64 bit distributions of Ethereum Wallet in the `resources/node/geth` subdirectory.