# Port 30303 error in Mist when I run geth with a different datadir

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I run `geth` with the following command. When I try to start Mist I get an error `30303: bind: address already in use`. Why and how can I fix it?

This is the command I use to run `geth`:

```
geth --datadir /media/user/sdcard/chaindata --ipcdisable console
```

The command specifies that the blockchain data should be downloaded to the SD card rather than to the internal hard drive. It works fine for running `geth` itself.

But when I try to start Mist I get various error message such as:

```
Node type: geth
Network: main
Platform: linux (Architecure x64)

...11.167721 ethdb/database.go:82] Alloted 512MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/ativera/.ethereum/chaindata
I0531 20:35:11.464852 ethdb/database.go:169] closed db:/home/ativera/.ethereum/chaindata
I0531 20:35:11.465825 ethdb/database.go:82] Alloted 512MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/ativera/.ethereum/chaindata
I0531 20:35:11.587973 ethdb/database.go:82] Alloted 16MB cache and 16 file handles to /home/ativera/.ethereum/dapp
I0531 20:35:11.844313 eth/backend.go:170] Protocol Versions: [63 62 61], Network Id: 1
I0531 20:35:11.844786 eth/backend.go:199] Blockchain DB Version: 3
I0531 20:35:11.845385 core/blockchain.go:206] Last header: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0531 20:35:11.845421 core/blockchain.go:207] Last block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0531 20:35:11.845440 core/blockchain.go:208] Fast block: #0 [d4e56740…] TD=17179869184
I0531 20:35:11.846587 p2p/server.go:311] Starting Server
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: address already in use
```

Why do I get the error message and more importantly, what should I do to be able to make Mist actually run when I start `geth` the way I do as specified above?

Answer (score 1):

**Q**: Why do I get the error message?

The reason why you are getting the error with port 30303 already being used is because your first `geth` command is using this port.

When you run Ethereum Wallet (Mist), it will try to start up another instance of `geth` because it is unable to detect the first running instance of `geth.

Mist communicates with `geth` through the IPC file. In Linux this IPC file is `$HOME/.ethereum/geth.ipc`.

Because you have disabled the IPC file, in your `geth` command, Mist is unable to detect the first running instance.

And if you did not disable the IPC socket, `geth` will create it in your specified datadir with the full file name `/media/user/sdcard/chaindata/geth.ipc`.

**Q**: What should I do to be able to make Mist actually run when I start Geth the way I do as specified above?

What you will need to do is start `geth` specifying the IPC file that Mist expects to use (see [How to change to private network in etherum wallet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/how-to-change-to-private-network-in-etherum-wallet/4429#4429) to details on the IPC file path hard coded in Mist):

```
geth --datadir /media/user/sdcard/chaindata --ipcpath $HOME/.ethereum/geth.ipc console
```

Then start Mist.

Answer (score 0):

First, your chaindata is corrupt. You need to remove the chaindata directory and sync again or use a valid chaindata backup.

Second why do disable ipc ?

Comment: I think it's necessary to disable ipc to get the command above to run according to some answer here on ethereum.stackexchange.com. I can try without it. Edit: I think ipcdisable has to be there otherwise will get this error: operation not permitted

Comment: But I'm not sure if it's really corrupt as Geth seems to run without problems.

Comment: Yes, Geth seems to be running fine. Maybe the directory of Mist have to be changed as well somehow to run when Geth --datadir is set to SD card?

Comment: you changed the log. In this case, you have already a process using the 30303 port. do a ps aux | grep eth ... Ethereum-wallet start a geth process. if  you want use your own geth process. Stop the wallet and start the geth command. When the wallet starts, it checks the port to know if there is already a geth working.