# Ethereum Wallet with private testnet not working: chaindata/LOCK:Permission Denied

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Trying to connect Ethereum Wallet with the private test net, but facing issues.

Ran this command:

```
geth --genesis /home/cgen.json --datadir '/home/systemname/Desktop/node2/geth.ipc ~/.ethereum/geth.ipc' --networkid 12345 --nodiscover --port 30302 --verbosity 0 console
```

And then launched Ethereum Wallet.

I got the error `ERROR: Could not open database open/home/systemname/.ethereum/chaindata/LOCK:Permission Denied`

[image]

Running the above mentioned but getting error .

Comment: Try running `geth` with `sudo`. @jassu

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 07/06/2016**

The problem you are getting with the chaindata being locked is because you have started one instance of `geth` and then Ethereum Wallet is trying to start another instance of `geth.

Before/when/after you get the error, in another terminal window, type

```
ps -ef | grep geth
```

If you see two instances of `geth`, this is the cause of your locking issue.

The cause of this is that Ethereum Wallet tries to communicate with any existing `geth` instance by using the IPC file and this is hardcoded in Ethereum Wallet to be `~/.ethereum/geth.ipc` . When Ethereum Wallet is unable to detect an existing `geth` instance, it will attempt to start a new `geth` instance, and this is when you have the locking issue.

To fix this issue, see the usage of the `--ipcpath ~/.ethereum/geth.ipc` command line parameter below.

---

Try the following:

1. Create a password file

   ```
   echo "testpassword" > /tmp/passwordfile
   ```
2. Create a new account using a temp datadir

   ```
   geth --dev --datadir /tmp/devdatadir --password /tmp/passwordfile account new
   ```
3. Run `geth` in mining mode

   ```
   geth --dev --datadir /tmp/devdatadir --mine --minerthreads 1 --password /tmp/passwordfile --ipcpath ~/.ethereum/geth.ipc console
   ```
4. Then running Ethereum Wallet. You should see a PRIVATE-NET indicator on the top of the Ethereum Wallet screen. And you should see your MAIN ACCOUNT (ETHERBASE) clicking out 5 ethers quite quickly.

If this works, set `--datadir` to your desired destination and use `/tmp/passwordfile` if you want to.

See also [How to change to private network in etherum wallet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/how-to-change-to-private-network-in-etherum-wallet/4429#4429)

Comment: Followed the steps mentioned above but getting the same error

Comment: Did you check to see if there was more than one instance of `geth` running?

Comment: Closed all terminals and started a new one  it returned -- 16620 16604  0 16:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto geth

Comment: Please check again just before you get the error message, then when you get the error message, then after you get the error message.

Comment: I ran the grep command after error and got this root      4387  2623 46 16:10 pts/2    00:02:00 geth --dev --datadir /tmp/devdatadir --mine --minerthreads 1 --password /tmp/passwordfile --ipcpath /home/lnfotech/.ethereum/geth.ipc console
lnfo+  4545  4531  0 16:14 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto geth

Comment: Did the lock error mention the lock is on /tmp/devdatadir/chaindata/LOCK or /home/infotech/.ethereum/chaindata/LOCK? What version Ethereum Wallet are you running? BTW, you can edit your original question to add further screens and info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40827/discussion-between-jassu-and-bokkypoobah).