# Custom token display in case of geth testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, testnets

From [this](https://www.ethereum.org/token), i found that
*To add a token to watch, go to the contracts page and then click "Watch Token". A pop-up will appear and you only need to paste the contract address. The token name, symbol and decimal number should be automatically filled.* 
How can i perform same thing in case of testnet. I mean how will a testnet user will see the tokens he possess.I am using GETH client and web3 to interact with node and pass related data to UI .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, you don't want to use the Ethereum Wallet to add the Watch Token function. Instead you want to use `geth` JavaScript to find the token balance.

If this is the case, you can use the same type of script as in [Script To Get Account Balances And Including TheDAO Tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3750/1268).

Your code would look like the following:

```
var tokenContractABI = {your token contract ABI};
var tokenContractAddress = "{your token contract address}";
var tokenContract = eth.contract(tokenContractABI).at(tokenContractAddress);
var tokens = tokenContract.balanceOf({user address});
console.log(tokens);
```

Comment: Here : https://www.ethereum.org/token, they provide an UI page to execute the token contract but in geth private blockchain , we use eth.getbalance(address) to see the balance.It just shows ether. So how can user check the tokens like that?

Comment: What operating system are you running? The reason why I'm asking is because you can run `geth` on a private network and connect the Ethereum Wallet to `geth` and EW will be your UI. See the answer to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5716/ethereum-wallet-with-private-testnet-not-working-chaindata-lockpermission-deni .

Comment: I saw your message about Windows, but it has disappeared. Check out http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4421/1268 . Message back if it does not work.

Comment: yeah, i saw the same after comment and then i deleted comment. I am trying to solve my purpose. In case of problem, i will be back to you.:)

Comment: @BookyPooBah I connected node with ethereum wallet. I have two accounts. Wallet is showing the balance of account2 but account1 which is etherbase is showing 0 balance. I can see the balance in account1 by geth cli.what to do?

Comment: In your WIndows Task Manager, check you are not running two instances of `geth`. You should be starting the first `geth` instance with the appropriate parameters, then run Ethereum Wallet. If your `geth` parameters are correct, Ethereum Wallet will connect to the `geth` instance you started. If not, Ethereum Wallet will try to start up a second `geth` instance.

Comment: I am running one geth instance in which i have created two accounts.I don't know what was the problem. I closed the geth instance and ran again now it is working fine.Thanks.